# The value of None

Tags: python, revitpythonshell

I am learning here...

I'm perplexed by the value of "None".  In the following snippet, I'm trying to find all the views where the view parameter called "View Owner" is either None, or != None.

The bellow snippet tells me I have a Views list length of 3548 items and the number of items that != None is 316.  If I change != to ==, the resultant is 0.  I don't understand how this can be... aren't thins either None or Not None? I would think the sum of both runs should - 3548.

```
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, BuiltInCategory, View

    uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
    doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document


        selection = [ doc.GetElement( elId ) for elId in __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.GetElementIds() ]

        views = []

        if len(selection) == 0:
            cl_views = FilteredElementCollector(doc)
            views = cl_views.OfCategory( BuiltInCategory.OST_Views ).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
        else:
            for sel in selection:
                if isinstance(sel, View):
                    views.append(sel)

        count = 0
        for v in views:
            if v.LookupParameter("View Owner")!=None:
                snumber = v.LookupParameter("View Owner").AsString()
                if snumber != None:
                    count= count+1
                    vowner = v.LookupParameter('View Owner').AsString()
                    if v.LookupParameter('View Name')!=None:
                        vname = v.LookupParameter('View Name').AsString()
                        vowner = vowner+vname
                    print(vowner)

        print len(views)
        print count
```

Comment: Testing for `None` is better done with `is` and `is not`

Comment: But you're doing `count = count+1` in the inner `for` loop, you've filtered some of the objects with the second `if`

Comment: You're right - I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
is None
```

And

```
is not None
```

instead `==` and `!=`

Comment: Thanks Martin and Moses.  The result is the same though.

Comment: My count is in the wrong place.  I wish  I could delete this question.

Comment: @MarekFalkowski You can delete the question, if you feel it wouldn't be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that should be avoided in the sample code snippet, IMHO:

- Comparing by name should always be avoided, if possible. It is language dependent and less efficient than comparing numbers. In this case, it is probably possible to replace the string comparisons by element id ones.
- Using LookupParameter is much less efficient than using a fixed built-in parameter enumeration value to retrieve the parameter you are interested in.